# White space under footer page on website

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, webforms

I have a white space under my website.
http://braulionova-001-site18.atempurl.com/DirectorioMedico.aspx
I check css, break tags.

Some pages are fine but other have this white space under footer page.

Comment: Element with that id `#ExtenderZipCodes1_completionListElem` has height:200px

Comment: which browser ? what version?

Comment: the last Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a class in a your css named `autocomplete_completionListElement` which has a been given a height of 200px. try commenting the height and check as givne below. Hope this helps.

```
.autocomplete_completionListElement {
visibility: hidden;
margin: 0px !important;
background-color: White;
background: white;
color: windowtext;
border: buttonshadow;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
cursor: 'default';
overflow: auto;
/* height: 200px; */
text-align: left;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the element `.autocomplete_completionListElement` has a `visibility: hidden` with height 200px.

`visibility: hidden` keeps the element there, with height and width but turns it invisible. Seems like you don't want it there since you tried hiding it. To get rid of it just use `display: none`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the element with class **.autocomplete_completionListElement**.

Update your code with the code below. It will work fine.

```
.autocomplete_completionListElement {
    /*visibility: hidden;*/
    display: none;
    margin: 0px !important;
    background-color: White;
    background: white;
    color: windowtext;
    border: buttonshadow;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    cursor: 'default';
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: ok, I thought it's a div which has some functionality and you want to hide it initially.. glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to This CSS code..

```
 .footer            
          { 
              background:#333333; 
              color:#848484;
              font-size:12px; 
              font-size:12px; 
              font-family:Open Sans,sans-serif;
              font-weight:bold;
              text-align:center;
              padding:7px 50px 10px 0px; 
              vertical-align:middle; 
              margin-top:10px;
          }
```

Comment: This question has already been answered, if you think the previous answers are wrong, be sure to point out what they are missing.